# MSSQL effective trigger INSTEAD OF INSERT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, database-trigger

I have a case when using instead-of-insert trigger is necessary. My colleagues and I wonder which one is more effective (memory usage, time to run, etc.).

The trigger checks whether the record exists in table, if no inserts the new row, otherwise updates existing row by its key. The primary key in this example is composite key of (DocumentId, VatRate).

The first variant is with checking whether the record already exists:

```
CREATE TRIGGER docvatsum_trg
ON DocumentVatSummary
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
      IF EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM DocumentVatSummary a
         JOIN inserted b ON (a.DocumentId = b.DocumentId AND a.VatRate = b.VatRate)
      )
      BEGIN
         UPDATE DocumentVatSummary
         SET 
            DocumentVatSummary.VatBase = i.VatBase, 
            DocumentVatSummary.VatTotal = i.VatTotal
         FROM inserted i
         WHERE 
            DocumentVatSummary.DocumentId = i.DocumentId AND
            DocumentVatSummary.VatRate = i.VatRate
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO DocumentVatSummary
         SELECT * FROM inserted
      END
END;
```

The second variant tries to insert and if insert fails an update follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER docvatsum_trg
ON DocumentVatSummary
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   SAVE TRANSACTION savepoint
   BEGIN TRY
      INSERT INTO DocumentVatSummary
      SELECT * FROM inserted
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
      IF XACT_STATE() = 1
         BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRAN savepoint

            UPDATE DocumentVatSummary
            SET 
               DocumentVatSummary.VatBase = i.VatBase,
               DocumentVatSummary.VatTotal = i.VatTotal
            FROM inserted i
            WHERE 
               DocumentVatSummary.DocumentId = i.DocumentId AND
               DocumentVatSummary.VatRate = i.VatRate
         END
   END CATCH
END;
```

Note: Rollback to savepoint is required, because of TRY-CATCH implementation in running transaction in TSQL.

Which one is better and why? If you have better solution, please share.

Comment: Ever hear of [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)?  will insert if not exists, and update if exists.  No need for all the checking.

Comment: @xQbert I'm a fan of `MERGE` too and still use it but I think this article should be made aware of. I found it educational. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: As others have said, use merge, but definitely don't use the second variant - you should not use exception handling for this kind of logic. You are making an assumption about why you have entered the catch block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MERGE in your trigger as explained here:

[MERGE SYNTAX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Code Example:

```
DECLARE @SummaryOfChanges TABLE(Change VARCHAR(20)); 

MERGE INTO Sales.SalesReason AS Target  
USING (VALUES ('Recommendation','Other'), 
              ('Review', 'Marketing'), 
              ('Internet', 'Promotion'))  
       AS Source (NewName, NewReasonType)  
ON Target.Name = Source.NewName  
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
UPDATE SET ReasonType = Source.NewReasonType  
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
INSERT (Name, ReasonType) VALUES (NewName, NewReasonType)  
OUTPUT $action INTO @SummaryOfChanges;
```